# no type or protocol named 'NFCragPeaderSessionDelegate' while building Xamarin.iOS uisng Xamarin froms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019

we are also facing same BUILD Issue of Xamarin.IOS a project once we update the VS and Xcode.
**no type or protocol named '**NFCragPeaderSessionDelegate**. (.71132627) registrar.h**

Can You Please let us How you have solved the above Issue?.

=== Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac ===

Version 8.9.6 (build 6)
Installation UUID: 8fdaed4e-5303-48fc-9d8b-ae46fbbac66c
GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
Xamarin.Mac 6.18.0.23 (d16-6 / 088c73638)

=== Apple Developer Tools ===

Xcode 12.4 (17801)
Build 12D4e

=== Xamarin.Mac ===

Version: 7.8.2.5 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 3836759d4
Branch: d16-9
Build date: 2021-02-10 17:56:43-0500

=== Xamarin.iOS ===

Version: 14.14.2.5 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 3836759d4
Branch: d16-9
Build date: 2021-02-10 17:56:44-0500

Comment: Is 'NFCragPeaderSessionDelegate' created by yourself? if not, maybe you can try to downgrade the ios version.

Comment: NFCragPeaderSessionDelegate is form NFC Lib.Sure we will try for downgrade